# How can I convert a character array to a binary array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a program that will take the input of a ppm image, read in the header and remaining pixel values, isolate the last values in the pixel values, and attempt to convert that string of binary numbers into a letter. It is not completed, but I'll include what I have so far. My question is how do I go from the array that is complete after the first for loop, to converting that array to a binary array in order to use the formula at the end of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if I need to clarify further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    //to read in the header of a ppm image
    char header[5];
    scanf("%s",header);
    int width, height, depth;
    scanf("%d %d %d\n", &width, &height, &depth);

    //isolating the last digit of the ppm values
    unsigned char rgb[width*height*3];
    int count = 0;
    for(count = 0; count < (width*height*3); count++){
        scanf("%c", &rgb[count]);
        rgb[count] = (long)rgb % 10;
    }

    //formula to convert a binary array to a letter
    int bin[9];
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char letter[1];
    for(i = 8; i >= 0; --i){
        result += (bin[i] * (int) pow(2, 8-i));
        letter[0] = result;
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    printf("%s\n", letter);


}
```

Comment: Don't use `pow` -- you **will** run into floating point accuracy problems. Simple bit shifting is enough to shift bits simply.

Comment: `(long)rgb % 10;` What do you mean?

Comment: Note: `char letter[1]` in conjunction with the expectations of `%s` receiving a terminated string isn't going to leave you any room for either (a) your data, or (b) the terminator, *both* of which would seem rather important. Perhaps `char letter[2] = {0};` was what you were shooting for. (and I didn't bother validating the actual algorithm, sry).

Comment: Rather than `(int) pow(2, 8-i)`, suggest `1u << (8-i)` or re-write as `result += bin[i] << (8-i);`